# Can't set tag/attribute value using c# codebehind on aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a custom .ascx control and would like to set one of it's properties using code.  In the .aspx I have this:

```
<uc1:CustomContent ID="bunchOfContent" runat="server" contentPayload='<%# getRegionID() %>' />
```

In the codebehind I have:

```
    public partial class Region : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
... things
        }

        public string getRegionID()
        {
            //return "region_" + Request["region"];
            return "thevalueIwant";
        }
```

However, the value I want is not populated and the code is not invoked (breakpoints are not triggered).

What am I doing wrong?  I've tried various changes like changing the quotes from " to ' to no quotes at all.  Also I've used <%= instead of <%# but no luck.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Page_Load` method, you can do:

```
bunchOfContent.contentPayload = getRegionID();
```

The reason why `<%# ... %>` did not work is because that's the form you use for databinding. In order for the code you put in there to be executed, you need to call the `DataBind()` method somewhere. And as for `<%= ... %>`, that's not suitable for setting a server control property, it simply is a short form of `<% Response.Write(...) %>`.

Comment: Boon!  This fixed it instantly!  I will erect a small shrine in your honour... :)

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation.  I do find it annoying deciding what syntax to use in different situations to call the code!  Practice, I guess :)